# Transitioning a path more than once

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, path, transition

I'm having trouble trying to create a transition of groups. I've created an object from a path based on x and y data. I want this object to transition horizontally 5 times. I have 5 groups that will use the same object and transition. I'm trying to use a for loop so I don't have to rewrite that transition 5 times. You'll see in the snippet I have the groups group1, group2, etc., that are meant to use the same object. Is it possible to create an array of those groups that can be used for the transition? Hopefully this isn't confusing, and I'm using d3.v4. Thank you for taking a look at this.

```
var width = 900
var height = 1200;

var canvas = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height);

// x and y coordinates of the path
var objectArray = [{x: 51, y: 44}, 
        {x: 51, y: 49}, 
        {x: 53, y: 50}, 
        {x: 53, y: 53}, 
        {x: 52, y: 53}, 
        {x: 52, y: 60}, 
        {x: 70, y: 85}, 
        {x: 71, y: 160}, 
        {x: 64, y: 181}, 
        {x: 54, y: 181}, 
        {x: 47, y: 170}, 
        {x: 43, y: 170}, 
        {x: 36, y: 181}, 
        {x: 26, y: 181}, 
        {x: 19, y: 160}, 
        {x: 19, y: 85}, 
        {x: 39, y: 60}, 
        {x: 39, y: 53}, 
        {x: 38, y: 53}, 
        {x: 38, y: 50}, 
        {x: 40, y: 49}, 
        {x: 40, y: 44}, 
        {x: 51, y: 44}];

var interpolate = d3.curveCardinal.tension(0.35);

var objectOutline = d3.line()
  .x(function(d, i) { return d.x / 2.6 })
  .y(function(d, i) { return d.y / 2.2 })
  .curve(interpolate);


// The 5 groups that use that same shapeArray for transition
var group1 = canvas.append('g');
var group2 = canvas.append('g');
var group3 = canvas.append('g');
var group4 = canvas.append('g');
var group5 = canvas.append('g');


// The group coordinates for start and end of transition
var locationArray = [{x:1200, y:440, xTransition:250},
                 {x:1200, y:440, xTransition:278},
                 {x:1200, y:440, xTransition:306},
                 {x:1200, y:440, xTransition:334},
                 {x:1200, y:440, xTransition:362}];

 var length = locationArray.length;

 for (var i=0; i < length; i++){

 // Right now the group1 group is being used for the path
 group1.selectAll('path')
    .data([objectArray])
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('d', objectOutline)
 group1.attr('transform','translate('+ locationArray[i].x + ','+ locationArray[i].y + ')')
    .transition()
    .duration((Math.random() * 3000) + 800)
    .delay(Math.random() * 3000)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + locationArray[i].xTransition + ',' + locationArray[i].y + ')');

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with a `for` loop is that it will run to the end in few milliseconds, that is, almost immediately. That's not how you create a series of transitions.

The idiomatic way for doing this is using `.on("end"...` at the end of each transition. For instance, in this snippet, I create a function named `transitioning` that is called when the transition ends. As you have just 5 elements in the array, I set a counter, and the transition is called only when the counter is < 5:

```
transitioning(1)

function transitioning(index) {
  console.log(locationArray[index].y)
  path.transition()
    .duration((Math.random() * 3000) + 800)
    .delay(Math.random() * 3000)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + locationArray[index].xTransition + ',' + locationArray[index].y + ')')
    .on("end", function() {
      if (++index > 4) return;
      transitioning(index)
    })
}
```

I'm starting at 1 because the bottle is already at position `0`. Also, it's funny that you're transitioning the group, not the path. I changed that. If that's not what you want, just use the same logic to the groups.

Here is your code with this new function:

```js
var width = 600
var height = 500;

var canvas = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height);

// x and y coordinates of the path
var objectArray = [{
  x: 51,
  y: 44
}, {
  x: 51,
  y: 49
}, {
  x: 53,
  y: 50
}, {
  x: 53,
  y: 53
}, {
  x: 52,
  y: 53
}, {
  x: 52,
  y: 60
}, {
  x: 70,
  y: 85
}, {
  x: 71,
  y: 160
}, {
  x: 64,
  y: 181
}, {
  x: 54,
  y: 181
}, {
  x: 47,
  y: 170
}, {
  x: 43,
  y: 170
}, {
  x: 36,
  y: 181
}, {
  x: 26,
  y: 181
}, {
  x: 19,
  y: 160
}, {
  x: 19,
  y: 85
}, {
  x: 39,
  y: 60
}, {
  x: 39,
  y: 53
}, {
  x: 38,
  y: 53
}, {
  x: 38,
  y: 50
}, {
  x: 40,
  y: 49
}, {
  x: 40,
  y: 44
}, {
  x: 51,
  y: 44
}];

var interpolate = d3.curveCardinal.tension(0.35);

var objectOutline = d3.line()
  .x(function(d, i) {
    return d.x / 2.6
  })
  .y(function(d, i) {
    return d.y / 2.2
  })
  .curve(interpolate);


// The 5 groups that use that same shapeArray for transition
var group1 = canvas.append('g');

// The group coordinates for start and end of transition
var locationArray = [{
  x: 200,
  y: 40,
  xTransition: 20
}, {
  x: 200,
  y: 40,
  xTransition: 80
}, {
  x: 200,
  y: 40,
  xTransition: 140
}, {
  x: 200,
  y: 40,
  xTransition: 220
}, {
  x: 200,
  y: 40,
  xTransition: 280
}];

var length = locationArray.length;

// Right now the group1 group is being used for the path
var path = group1.selectAll('path')
  .data([objectArray])
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', objectOutline)
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + locationArray[0].xTransition + ',' + locationArray[0].y + ')')

transitioning(1)

function transitioning(index) {
  path.transition()
    .duration((Math.random() * 3000) + 800)
    .delay(Math.random() * 1000)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + locationArray[index].xTransition + ',' + locationArray[index].y + ')')
    .on("end", function() {
      if (++index > 4) return;
      transitioning(index)
    })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's definitely good to know but not exactly what I am looking for. I'm trying to make it so there are 5 object/bottles, ending at their xTransitions--not 1 bottle completing completing all the xTransitions in the array. So you'd see the 5 bottles transitioning on the screen at the same time. I created the 5 groups for each bottle, but am trying to avoid writing the same transition for each one. Sorry I wasn't very clear on this. I should have included the same .selectAll('path') for each group, not just group1. Thanks for your help and let me know if my explanation is not clear.